# pyinstaller - Library missing while converting to .exe from dist

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I know people have asked similar question but here I know the issue and manual fix as well but trying to make it fix automatically ..

I am converting a simple Python code to .exe using pyinstaller.

```
1st approach-
pyinstaller.exe test.py
```

test.py includes library `docx` . When the `dist` folder is created it is missing the `docx` library from the folder, however I can see `lxml` is there . I have to manually copy the `docx` library folder from my Python `Lib`  to the created `dist` then only the `.exe` is executing correctly otherwise its throwing error of missing docx.default from template ..

I tried below way as well to create a single file but same issue.

```
pyinstaller --onefile test.py
```

Need yours suggestion or fix. Also, if this all can be fixed in a single file that will be great using 2nd approach